# Pypy specific error

Tags: python, pypy

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#!/usr/bin/env pypy

class my_components(object):
    COMP0 = 0
    COMP1 = 1
    COMP1 = 2
    __IGNORECOMP = -1

def attribute_dictionary(o):
    d = { }
    for attr in dir(o):
        if attr[:2] != '__':
            print o,attr
            d[attr] = o.__getattribute__(o, attr)
    return d

def main():
    print attribute_dictionary(my_components)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

that I use to effectively do fancy enum in python.

It works great in python, prints:

```
<class '__main__.my_components'> COMP0
<class '__main__.my_components'> COMP1
<class '__main__.my_components'> _my_components__IGNORECOMP
{'COMP0': 0, 'COMP1': 2, '_my_components__IGNORECOMP': -1}
```

However, when I run it with pypy (switch first two lines) it fails with:

```
<class '__main__.my_components'> COMP0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_main.py", line 53, in run_toplevel
  File "./pypy_Test.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "./pypy_Test.py", line 21, in main
    print attribute_dictionary(my_components)
  File "./pypy_Test.py", line 17, in attribute_dictionary
    d[attr] = o.__getattribute__(o, attr)
TypeError: unbound method __getattribute__() must be called with my_components instance as first argument (got type instance instead)
```

Any insights would be most welcome.

-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeError: unbound method `__getattribute__()` must be called with
>   my_components instance as first argument (got type instance instead)

This is saying that (at least with PyPy), the first argument to `__getattribute__` must be an instance of the class `my_components`.

Instead, `o` is the class `my_components` itself, not an instance.

Try changing

```
d[attr] = o.__getattribute__(o, attr)
```

to

```
d[attr] = getattr(o, attr)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `__getattribute__` passing in the *class*, not an instance of that class. From the [`__getattribute__` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__):

> Called unconditionally to implement attribute accesses for instances of the class.

The fact that this works at all with the class as a first argument in cPython is a happy coincidence; officially, the first argument should be an instance instead.